# Laravel, with NuSOAP in a controller, does not work

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, soap, laravel-5

Having a NuSOAP web service defined in an inline route closure function works great, but having it in a route closure controller does not.

#### Example: working

**routes.php:**

```
Route::any('api', function() {
    require_once ('nusoap.php');
    $server = new \nusoap_server();

    $server->configureWSDL('TestService', false, url('api'));

    $server->register('test',
        array('input' => 'xsd:string'),
        array('output' => 'xsd:string'),
    );

    function test($input){
        return $input;
    }

    $rawPostData = file_get_contents("php://input");
    return \Response::make($server->service($rawPostData), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1'));
});
```

**SOAP Test Client**

```
require_once('nusoap.php');

$client = new \nusoap_client('http://my-laravel-installation.com/api?wsdl', true);

$result = $client->call("test", "HelloWorld");

print_r($result); exit();
```

**response**

> HelloWorld

This works as expected.

#### Example: not working

Moving the code to a dedicated controller breaks it:

**routes.php:**

```
Route::any('api', 'SoapController@server');
```

**SoapController.php:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SoapController extends Controller {

    public function server() {
        require_once ('nusoap.php');
        $server = new \nusoap_server();

        $server->configureWSDL('TestService', false, url('api'));

        $server->register('test',
            array('input' => 'xsd:string'),
            array('output' => 'xsd:string'),
        );

        function test($input){
            return $input;
        }

        $rawPostData = file_get_contents("php://input");
        return \Response::make($server->service($rawPostData), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1'));
    }

}
```

**SOAP Test Client**

```
require_once('nusoap.php');

$client = new \nusoap_client('http://my-laravel-installation.com/api?wsdl', true);

$result = $client->call("test", "HelloWorld");

print_r($result); exit();
```

**response**

> "method 'test' ('test') not defined in service('' '')

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. Install a fresh copy of Laravel v5.2.45
2. Download the last NuSOAP version (v0.9.5)
3. Define the route for the NuSOAP Web Service - copy and paste the code from above
4. Create the SoapController - copy and paste the code from above
5. Create a new temp route to act as the SOAP client, and copy and paste the code beneath **SOAP Test Client** above into this route's closure function
6. Load the temp route page in the browser to execute a SOAP call to the Web Service

#### Conclusion:

This indicates, that for some reason, the output is different when using an inline route function versus using a dedicated route controller.

How could this be?

#### Your insight greatly appreciated:

If you have:

- any experience with this and you have a solution
- or, you have an idea on why this could occur
- or, you have any thoughts on why having the NuSOAP code in the controller generates a different response than having it in an inline route function

...please chime in.

Thank you for your thoughts!

Answer (score 3):

I have a simple solution for this.

Just install [nusoap](https://github.com/econea/nusoap) via composer.

1. `composer require econea/nusoap`
2. Call nusoap as needed:

   ```
   $client = new \nusoap_client('http://my-laravel-installation.com/api?wsdl', true);
   ```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF validation should be passive for current laravel versions.

app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php

protected $except = [
        'your way'
    ];

Must be.